# Node.js API Architecture

Tags: node.js, api-design, mongodb

I am currently working on  a web app and want to design the interface between nodejs / mongoose and the backbone app.

A short description of the app:
A user signs up to the application and gets a user account where he can create an organization (e.g. footballclub). Within these organizations you can set up projects. Within these projects you can define tasks you could assign to somebody)

I want to have a RESTful api for the app. My problem is: A user could have more than one organization, if i have an api for projects like

GET /projects/
POST /projects/
GET /projects/:id
PUT /projects/:id
DELETE /projects/:id

How do i determine to which organization the project belongs? Do i add a parameter to the api or do i send an extra field containing the id of the organization? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GET /organizations/projects/:id

Gets a  list of projects for an organization.

> POST /projects/:id

Updates a specific project.

> GET /projects/:id

Gets a specific project.

> DELETE /projects/:id

Deletes a specific project.

> DELETE /organizations/:id

Deletes an organization and all it's projects.

> POST /organizations/:id

Updates a specific organization.

> GET /organizations

Gets a list of all organizations